# App Transport Security with Advertisements

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I'm working on an app for a client that uses freewheel.tv to serve video ads. From what I can tell, freewheel allows ad providers to host their own ads which means that the ad domains are dynamic. I know that after the 1st, Apple is discouraging apps from setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true. I have read some posts about Apple allowing exceptions for certain scenarios but am hesitant to rely on that.

What is the best way to handle this scenario? Do I just explain to my client that we will have to present our use case to Apple and hope they approve it or is there something else I can do? Any guidance here will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Judging based on this video and many other resources [What's New in Security](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/706/?time=250) you will need to provide Apple with a sufficient explanation **why** you need to have this exception. It's probably a good idea to get in touch with them ASAP.

Comment: Seems like Apple has just extended the deadline for ATS https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12212016b

Answer (score -1):

Having a lot of experience with the Apple approval process, I can tell you that I'd be the most surprised person in the world if they let your app go in with the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` flag set to true and refuse everyone else's. The bottom line is that if freewheel.tv wants to keep doing business on iOS devices, they will have to find a solution for their customer to allow specific domains or make it a hard requirement to serve ads over HTTPS.

I highly doubt that having a conversation with Apple (if you can even get a hold of them for this) will any difference.

To solve your problem, you will either have to allow every domain you know is serving ads in your info.plist or change ads provider.

Comment: So you don't think Apple will stand by their statements that they will be allowing some apps into the store with ATS exceptions turned on, if there is sufficient justification?  At no point has Apple said that no apps will be approved if they set the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to true.  They just said that developers will need to provide justification.  No one knows at this point what justifications will be accepted.

Comment: Given that Apple has removed the 3.5mm jack and allowed only USB-C on the new MBP, you can't be safe enough when it comes to Apple. You either jump on the boat, or drown. I prefer my apps to stay on the boat :)

Comment: That said, I wasn't saying they wouldn't approve it, but making business decisions based on what Apples allows is shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: For the most part, with devs, Apple has been pretty good at giving people fair warning.  They gave people half a year to stop blindly disabling ATS because of what many SO answers propose as a "fix".  It will be a rough transition for developers who don't stay up to dat on Apple's recommended best practices.  Apple told devs for years to use Autolayout, but there were still many apps that looked like crap on the 6 / 6+... There's only so much you can do.

Comment: I agree that it is dagngerouse to base business decisions on hoping Apple will do something, but if you literally have no way to comply with ATS because you don't control some of the servers, that seems to be a valid reason.  Also, your solution will still require justification from Apple, because if you add `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` for a domain, you will still be required to provide justification.  Your response may make the app more secure, and may make justification easier, but I bet the OP would not be able to anticipate all domains used by the advertising provider.